# php: preg_match: stop searching if any element of pattern exists within text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$pattern = '/^(^[\`\~\@\#\$\%\^\&\\])+$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $textToSearch)){
   exit('Bad text.');
}
```

The code above is supposed to exit upon the first occurrence of any element in the pattern above. But it is not working. Will anyone please help me arrive at a working code sample?

Answer (score 1):

Since any occurrence of any of the listed special characters should mark the input as bad, you can make use of the regex: `` [\`\~\@\#\$\%\^\&\\\\] ``:

```
$pattern = '/[\`\~\@\#\$\%\^\&\\\\]/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $textToSearch)){
   exit('Bad text.');
}
```

[**Ideone link**](http://www.ideone.com/p2jsl)

Comment: +1, and a virtual +1 for correctly escaping the backslash, but you don't have to escape any of those other characters: http://www.ideone.com/O0t35